# Issue with rectangular patches using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating rectangular patches as shown below but some rectangles have different sizes even though I am using a constant dimension. I want all rectangles to be of the same size. How do I fix this?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib import cm

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

n=67
i=1
j=5
Factor=1000
for i in range(0, n):
    rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((Factor+Factor*i, Factor+Factor*j), 10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
    ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = Factor*1.1*n)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = Factor*1.1*n)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Tried your code and didn't see different size of rectangles. Should be display issue. Try to enlarge your figure by using `figsize` in subplots,  `fig,ax = plt.subpots(1, figsize=(30,10))`. If still have issue, please let us know your python/matplotlib version.

Comment: You can use `Rectangle(..., snap=False)` to prevent matplotlib from snapping lines to pixel position.  For very short distances, this won't be 100% perfect, but it will look more evenly.